# Is there any method to print the value that user input with array?

Tags: c

It prints the wrong number/random number. What I want is to print numbers higher than `75`.

```
int main() {
    int array[5];
    int num, i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        printf("Input Num %d : ", i);
        scanf("%d", &num);
    }
    if (num >= 75) {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten that array indexes are *zero* based. I.e. an array of `5` elements have valid indexes from `0` to `4` (inclusive).

Comment: You scanf `num`, but print `array[5]`

Comment: Besides my previous comment, please do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) on your code. It might prove helpful.

Comment: In addition to the other comments: your program asks for 5 numbers but you forgot to put them into the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use if within "for" loop. and please change "array" to "arr" or another name. The array will be a keyword in c++ sometime. should not use "array" to name a variable. here is my solution:

```
int main() {
    int arr[5];
    int num, i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        printf("Input Num %d : ", i);
        num = 0;
        scanf("%d", &num);
        arr[i-1] = num;

    }

    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        if (arr[i - 1] >= 75) {
            printf("%d\n", arr[i - 1]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should we really care about a future keyword in an unrelated language? It only causes trouble if you use the wrong compiler. Better get some error messages than some hidden problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors:

1. You iterate over the wrong set. Arrays in C start from 0, NOT 1.
2. You never set any value for array. What should it contain then? Random stuff of course. You could avoid it by initializing your array to zero. That way you know you are not writing to your `array` if you get zeros in your output.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int array[5] = {};
  int num = 0,i;

  for ( i = 0; i <5; i++) {
    printf("Input Num %d : ",i );
    scanf("%d",&num );
    array[i] = num;
  }
  for ( i = 0; i <5; i++) {
      if (array[i] >= 75) {
          printf("%d\n",array[i]);
      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: of course. I wasn't paying attention. Thank you @chqrlie.

Comment: num variable should be initialized in case of scanf function was failed.  num = 0; should be added before scanf calls.

Comment: @LocTran, ah! I didn't know that. Thanks for the tip. Edited as suggested.